# Trying to copy the longest word using function with pointers

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void longest_word(char *str[100], char *max[20]) {
    int i,j,length,longest,start,end;
    length=strlen(str);
    longest=0; start=0; end=0;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if (str[i]=' ')
        {
            length=end-start;
            if (longest < length)
                for (j=0;j<length;j++)
                {
                    max[j]=str[start];
                    start++;
                }
                longest = length;
            start=i+1;
        }
        else
        {
            end++;
        }
    }


}

int main()
{
    char str[100]="Happiness can be found even in the darkest of places";
    char max[20], min[20];

    longest_word(str,max);
    printf("Longest word is %c",max);
    return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to copy the longest word from a given string. Although using this function, it's not really working out. Not sure if my logic is flawed or the way I copy the letters to the `max[20]` string. Any ideas?

Comment: `void longest_word(char *str[100], char *max[20])` should be `void longest_word(char str[100], char max[20])`. What you have, is arrays of **pointers** to `char`, instead of arrays of `char`.

Comment: Your compiler should complain about the `longest_word` call. Listen to the compiler, it knows these things.

Comment: You also have the wrong formatter in `printf("Longest word is %c",max);` Please use `%s` here. And you forgot to terminate the `max[]` string.

Comment: I'm trying to use pointers since that's how my teacher wants me to do programs lately ...

Comment: I changed %c to %s and *max[20] to *max , respectively *str[100] to *str . Still, not working

Comment: @manubmxnsb, `char *str[100]` and `char *str` describe different kinds of objects.  The latter is consistent with what you're trying to do; the former, not.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i changed it to *str and still no solution

Comment: `=` is the *assignment* operator.  To *compare* two values, use `==`.  That is, `if (str[i]=' ')` should be `if (str[i]==' ')`.

Comment: Did you edit the code because you posted the wrong code, or to show corrections following comments? If the latter, please don't or you'll end up with a question that has no purpose, and comments that make no sense. If you want to post updated code, then add the updated code instead of removing errors which are the cause of the question. This isn't a step-by-step tutorial exchange, and there might be other faults in the code.

Comment: Be sure to test your final code with at least three test strings: one with the longest word at the beginning, one with it in the middle, and one with it at the end. Right now, your code will fail with the latter test case, for example.

Comment: Additionally, C is not Python: indentation is not significant.  Your statement `longest=length;` appears to be intended to be executed only subject to the condition that `longest < length` evaluates true, but in fact it is outside the scope of that `if` statement.  To avoid this kind of error, make a habit of *always* putting braces around the bodies of `if` statements, `else` statements, and loops, even when the body consists only of a single statement.  The only exception is in `if` ... `else if` chains, around the intermediate `else` blocks.

Comment: @JohnBollinger true! thank you. Its still not quite right, as it prints "Happiness ` "

Comment: WeatherVane already told you that you need to terminate the output string.

Comment: @WeatherVane how do i terminate the string?

Comment: By writing the `'\0'` nul terminator at the next position in the array after the last character you wrote there. For example after the innermost `j` loop: `max[j] = '\0';`

Comment: Alas! It works, finally! Thank you lots and sorry for your trouble guys!